# Can't connect to remote machine. net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, flask, geoserver, cesiumjs

I am using Nginx server and Ubuntu for my website. My geoserver is running and functioning well. I pass data to geoserver through:

```
const terrainProvider = await Cesium.GeoserverTerrainProvider({ 
"url": "http://10.131.2.23:8080/geoserver", 
"layerName": "cesium:raw_data_wms" }); 
const imageryProvider = new Cesium.WebMapServiceImageryProvider({ 
"url": "http://10.131.2.23:8080/geoserver/wms", 
"parameters": { "format": "image/png", "transparent": true }, 
"layers": "cesium:imegary-wms", "maximumLevel": 15 });
```

When I run FlaskApp the app works well, but when I try to enter the website the map page shows error as

```
Cesium.js:82     GET http://10.131.2.23:8080/geoserver/ows?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&tiled=true net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
Et._Implementations.loadWithXhr @ Cesium.js:82
n.requestFunction @ Cesium.js:82
UJ @ Cesium.js:82
jo.request @ Cesium.js:82
Et._makeRequest @ Cesium.js:82
Et.fetch @ Cesium.js:82
Et.fetchXML @ Cesium.js:82
Et.fetchXML @ Cesium.js:82
$ @ GeoserverTerrainProvider.js:1
ue @ GeoserverTerrainProvider.js:1
init @ map:58
(anonymous) @ map:93
map:92 Uncaught (in promise) FJ {statusCode: undefined, response: undefined, responseHeaders: undefined}response: undefinedresponseHeaders: undefinedstatusCode: undefined[[Prototype]]: ObjecttoString: ƒ ()constructor: ƒ FJ(e,t,n)[[Prototype]]: Object
init @ map:92
await in init (async)
(anonymous) @ map:93
```

Comment: does the url `http://10.131.2.23:8080/geoserver/ows?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities` return anything in your browser?

Comment: it takes really long time but doesn't return anything. Loading never ends.

Comment: So there is a connection problem between your client and server

Comment: any ways to fix this?

Comment: check the cable, firewall etc - it's not a GeoServer issue as you say that is working fine